# Cakephp saving multiple records at once

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to use save more then one record in cakephp using the `$this->save();` function?

Answer (score 4):

`save()` is used to simply save a model:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

Assuming the above information was stored in an array called $data, one would call

```
    $this->ModelName->save($data);
```

in order to `INSERT` a record into the model's table (if id field is not specified) or `UPDATE` a record of the model's table (if id field is specified).

`saveAll()` is used to:

Save multiple records of a model

```
Array
(
    [Article] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 1
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 2
        )
    )
)
```

So, you may save many models at the same time instead of looping and using save() each time.

**Save related records of a model**

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [username] => billy
    )
    [Profile] => Array
    (
        [sex] => Male
        [occupation] => Programmer
    )
)
```

This would save both `User` and `Profile` models at the same time. Otherwise, you would have to call `save()` for User first, obtain the `id` of the newly saved user and then save `Profile` with `user_id` set to the obtained `id`.

> Examples taken straight from [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 $dataMulti = array(
        array(
            'Info' =>
            array(
                'note' => "This is note 1",
                'delete_flag' => "f"
            )
        ),
        array(
            'Info' =>
            array(
                'note' => "This is note 2",
                'delete_flag' => "f"
            )
        ),
        array(
            'Info' =>
            array(
                'note' => "This is note 3",
                'delete_flag' => "f"
            )
        ),
    );
```

Save many records in once time
We have two way belows:

```
1. $infoModel->saveAll($dataMulti);
```

or

```
2. $infoModel->saveMany($dataMulti);
```